# Can a multi-secondary transformer be used with a full wave rectifier?

Tags: transformer, dc, rectifier

I got this board and from what I see, it should be used with a center tapped transformer with 0-9-18 as secondary because it uses a full wave rectifier:

[image: Board]

I have a normal transformer with 4 secondary pairs:
18-0 18-0 9-0 9-0

Is it possible to use this transformer with the before mentioned board? Any suggestion?

Comment: Your assertion that it should be used with an 18-0-9 secondary is inexplicable.

Comment: Instead of asking "is it possible" making this a yes/no question you could do a little bit of research on how transformers work and then it will be **obvious** what the answer will be.

Comment: That's not an 18-0-9 secondary in your diagram, it's a 0-9-18. Or, more usually, 9-0-9.

Comment: My electronics knowledge is very limited. I just happened to have this stuff around and wanted to get 12v DC out of it... So i apologize for the trivial mistakes. Reasearching how transformers work would mean putting an unjustified effort into this. If the question doesn't belong to this community, i guess i will remove it and we will be friends like before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned current ratings, or anything like that.  But, in general, yes you can.

Wire the two 0-9V secondaries in series.  Make sure you connect the "9V" end of one secondary to the "0V" end of the other, or it won't work.

The point where you joined the two secondaries becomes the centre tap.